# Emberjs - how to retrieve custom headers and render in view

Tags: ember.js, response-headers

So I had a look at [this](http://www.codeandtechno.com/code/2015/7/8/metadata-via-response-headers-in-emberjs)

and so I created /adapters/application.js

```
MyApp.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
 handleResponse: function(status, headers, payload) {
   meta = {
     msg: headers["X-Message"],
     type: headers["X-Message-Type"]
   };
   payload.meta = meta;
   return this._super(status, headers, payload);
  }
});
```

I added this to the correct controller:

```
  message: function() {
    return (this.get('MyApp.meta.msg'));
  }.property('MyApp.meta.msg')
```

I tried to access this in the handlebars template with

```
{{message}}
```

but I get nothing rendered (and no errors in the console either). I can confirm that the headers do exist in the response (and they have data).

What am I missing here? In Ember Inspector 'meta' is empty and message is undefined, so it is not seeing either of these!

**UPDATE**

As per Jeff's comment I tried updating the message definition with both `game.meta.msg` and `parent.meta.msg` but that also fails. Here is the full controller:

```
MyApp.GamesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['parent'],
  parent: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.parent.model'),
  sortProperties: ['in_default_set:asc', 'position:asc'],
  sortedGames: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties'),

  message: function() {
    return (this.get('parent.meta.msg'));
  }.property('parent.meta.msg')
});
```

Comment: What version of Ember are you using?

Comment: @locks Ember: 1.12.1 Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.19.1

Comment: I didn't check it now, but I think you should get the meta-data like so: `this.get('model.meta.msg')` - `model` might need to be smth else, depending on what model you have in that route/controller, but I'm pretty sure `MyApp.meta...` is wrong.

Comment: @Jeff thanks, I think you might be correct. I tried different things in there but it still says that message is undefined. I will add the full controller code, as it is a bit unusual (I did not write it)

Comment: If we were to follow the documentation example(https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/handling-metadata/), the right way would be this.get('parent.content.meta.msg'). I would be tempted to give it a try.

Comment: have you found a solution yet ?

Comment: no, I gave up on the idea as I could not get it to work